# Select Object expression with a variable contain spaces in power shell

Tags: powershell

The below does not work if the $_.FullName contains spaces.  I tried to use single quotes , double quotes nothing works. if I run it stand alone it works. It doesnt works with the Expression in Select-Object.  Please help me

```
Expression={unzip -q -c $($._FullName) META-INF/MANIFEST.MF |findstr 
Implementation-Version}}
```

I am using the above expression to find out the implementation version of a jar file

Comment: Should that be Powershell? What is it what you actually want to do? Shouldn't it be `$_.FullName`  (including the dot after the underline)?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes.  I updated it.  I need to find the implementation version of the jar file.   It works on a stand alone script but not with in the select object expression

Comment: what language is that? it doesn't look like any version of powershell ... [*frown*]

Answer (score 0):

To get back ticks to show, need to make this an answer not comment...

Your example is not complete, but using my powers of SWAG, your issue could be needing to add quotes.

```
-c `"$($_.FullName)`"
```